# Extern Struct in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm using extern to fetch variables from another class, and it works fine for int's, float's etc...

But this doesn't work, and I don't know how to do it:

Class1.cpp

```
struct MyStruct {
 int x;
}

MyStruct theVar;
```

Class2.cpp

```
extern MyStruct theVar;

void test() {
 int t = theVar.x;
}
```

It doesn't work because Class2 doesn't know what MyStruct is.

How do I fix this?

I tried declaring the same struct in Class2.cpp, and it compiled, but the values were wrong.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You put the `struct MyStruct` type declaration in a `.h` file and include it in both class1.cpp and class2.cpp.

IOW:

Myst.h

```
struct MyStruct {
 int x;
};
```

Class1.cpp

```
#include "Myst.h"

MyStruct theVar;
```

Class2.cpp

```
#include "Myst.h"

extern struct MyStruct theVar;

void test() {
 int t = theVar.x;
}
```

Comment: Should the definition for the struct also be in the header? Or can the definition be split off into the source .cpp?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define your struct in a class or common header file. Make sure you include this initial definition by means of `#include "Class1.h"` for instance.

Then, you need to modify your statement to say `extern struct MyStruct theVar;`

This statement does not need to be in a header file. It can be global.

Edit: Some .CPP file needs to contain the original declaration. All `extern` does is tell the compiler/linker to trust you that it exists somewhere else and when the program is built, it will find the valid definition. If you don't define `struct MyStruct theVar` somewhere, it likely won't compile all the way anyways when it reaches the linker.

Comment: This is sufficient to tell the compiler that `MyStruct` exists, but will fail as soon as you try to access any members.